# Two Play deployments servers on the one physical server

Tags: nginx, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to have two Play Framework deployments on the same server and configure nginx to redirect the locations accordingly.

I have this configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location /site2 {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }

    location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

What I want is:

1. When I use: http://ip/ or http://ip/something the Play deployment at port 9000 should respond.
2. When I use: http://ip/site2/ or http://ip/site2/something the Play deployment at port 8000 should respond.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

First, please check that you have access to each app directly:

- [ip:8000](http://ip:8000)
- [ip:9000](http://ip:9000)

Next please add `proxy_redirect` directive:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  localhost;

   location /site2 {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
      proxy_redirect http://localhost/site2/ http://localhost:8000/;
   }

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
      proxy_redirect http://localhost/ http://localhost:9000/;
   }
}
```